How to determine an unknown breakpoint in a linear regression model
[enter image description here][1]I am trying to figure out how to determine the breakpoint in a linear regression model. I have an example graph of what my series of data looks like and the corresponding code. There is a clear change in the linear trend of the curve, but my actual data is more difficult to decipher. I want to use a validated method in R that will determine the unknown "breakpoint", or the change in the linear regression. I would want something that would calculate the least sum of squares to determine the most optimal breakpoint. Does anyone know how I can determine a single breakpoint in this curve? See image link to view graph.
expdata
plot(speed, HR, data = expdata)
ggplot(expdata, aes(x=speed, y=HR)) + geom_point()
```


````{r}
expdata
plot(speed, HR, data = expdata)
ggplot(expdata, aes(x=speed, y=HR)) + geom_point()
```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/L3fG8.png

